# Cannot assign value of type ViewController to type UITabBarControllerDelegate?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, swift2

I have spent a few hours on this one, as I thought first that it was again an issue while migrating to swift2 with AnyObject versus PFObject. But apparently not! Here is the code:

```
class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, TimelineComponentTarget {
var timelineComponent: TimelineComponent<Post, TimelineViewController>!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timelineComponent = TimelineComponent(target: self)
    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}
```

Xcode returns on the 'self' of the last line:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'TimelineViewController' to type 'UITabBarControllerDelegate?'
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I would love to finally compile my code :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understood from the error message that I was trying to assign `self`  as the `delegate` of a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

Or the `TimeLineViewController` is not a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. I have therefore adopt this protocol.

```
class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, TimelineComponentTarget, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
```

It now works properly. Thanks!